# How do you use Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

I want to use coffeescript in a website, but something doesn't seem to be working. I have my coffeescript in a external file and it is linked to the html file. I have the coffeescript compiler also linked to the html file. What's wrong?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="coffee-script.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/coffeescript' src='Test.coffee'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Coffeescript:

```
$->
random = (number) ->
    console.log Math.ceil(Math.random() * number)
    $("body").append(number)


random(2)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the CoffeeScript import script type be text/javascript?

Comment: @tenub I don't, and never plan on using it, but can you give a reason? I just want to hear why

Comment: You will have better results if you first compile your CoffeeScript into JavaScript. This is a development time operation done before publishing your HTML. Read the 'Installation' and 'Usage' section on the CoffeeScript website.

http://coffeescript.org/#overview

Comment: @Ian I have used javascript before, and I feel that it is very messy and confusing. Also, I have a large javascript file that I am planning to rewrite and debug, and I figured it would be a good time to switch.

Comment: @LukeK I wasn't questioning your use of it; I was questioning a comment that has been deleted because they said coffeescript is worthless. You can use whatever library you want!

Comment: @Ian oh that's fine, but I can't start to use coffeescript if I can't get this problem fixed.

Comment: because it makes code harder to read for the sole purpose of reducing the amount of code to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to compile your Coffeescript to Javascript before publication:

> Once installed, you should have access to the coffee command, which
>   can execute scripts, ***compile .coffee files into .js***, and provide an
>   interactive REPL.

Source: http://coffeescript.org/#usage

Comment: What is an interactive REPL?

Comment: @LukeK: It's short for "read-eval-print loop." It gives you a prompt where you type it code and it evaluates the code and prints the result, then you get to do it again.